# Getting async await and task working

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin.ios, async-await, restsharp

I am trying to build a MonoTouch application that calls a rest API, and then processes the data it gets back. I had this all successfully working, but I am now trying to make it asynchronous, and displaying a 'waiting' overlay whilst it processes. I have now got the call to work using the RestSharp ExecuteAsync method, however I am not sure how to update my UI with the response.

This is inside the ViewController where I call my API class:

```
public partial class TestViewController : UIViewController
{
    partial void LoginButton_click(UIButton sender)
    {
        hud = new MTMBProgressHUD(View)
        {
            LabelText = "Waiting...",
            RemoveFromSuperViewOnHide = true,
        };

        View.AddSubview(hud);
        hud.Show(animated: true);


        APIClient ApiClient = new APIClient();
        TestAPI cd = new TestAPI(ApiClient);
        cd.TestApiCall(1, 123); //Could send this as sender parameter

        //Need to call this once the API call is complete
        //hud.Hide(animated: true);

    }
}
```

This is my TestAPI class where the api is called:

```
class TestAPI
{
    APIClient API;
    public TestAPI(APIClient APIClient)
    {
        this.API = APIClient;
    }

    public void TestApiCall(int userId, int PIN)
    {
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest("TestCall", Method.POST);

        OpenRequest obj = new OpenRequest
        {
            User = userId,
            PIN = PIN
        };

        request.AddObject(obj);

        API.client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
        {
            callback(response.Content);
        });
    }
    private void callback(string p)
    {
        //Could pass through the sender from the API call then do: sender.DismissHUD();

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I've read quite a bit about async, task and await but I just can't seem to get them to work with RestSharp in the way I want. I could send the calling ViewController method as a sender parameter, when create the TestAPI class and then reference back to this in the callback function, but this doesn't make the code very reusable elsewhere in the application.

Comment: RestSharp probably has async support by now in the form of the TAP. If not, write a wrapper. Then use async/await like normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we can do is wrap `RestClient.ExecuteAsync<T>` inside a method which returns a `Task<T>` and is implemented using the *Task Asynchronous Pattern* with the help of a `TaskCompletionSource`

First, lets wrap the `ExecuteAsync<T>` call inside the TestAPI class:

```
class TestAPI
{
    APIClient API;
    public TestAPI(APIClient APIClient)
    {
        this.API = APIClient;
    }

    public Task<T> ExecuteAsync<T>() where T : new()
    {
        var client = new RestClient();
        var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();

        RestRequest request = new RestRequest("TestCall", Method.POST);

        OpenRequest obj = new OpenRequest
        {
            User = userId,
            PIN = PIN
        };

        request.AddObject(obj);
        try
        {
            client.ExecuteAsync<T>(request, (response) => taskCompletionSource.SetResult(response.Data));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            taskCompletionSource.SetException(e);
        }

        return taskCompletionSource.Task;
    }
}
```

Now, you can `await` your call inside the controller:

```
public partial class TestViewController : UIViewController
{
    // I Assume this is a top level event handler, hence why
    // it returns void and not Task
    public async void LoginButton_click(UIButton sender)
    {
        hud = new MTMBProgressHUD(View)
        {
            LabelText = "Waiting...",
            RemoveFromSuperViewOnHide = true,
        };

        View.AddSubview(hud);
        hud.Show(animated: true);


        APIClient ApiClient = new APIClient();
        TestAPI cd = new TestAPI(ApiClient);
        var apiResponse = await cd.ExecuteAsync<YourType>();

        hud.Hide(animated: true);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, that seems like a better approach. I have now adapted it for a GET request and tried to de-serialize the response, but it's not returning anything. Is there anything special that needs doing on a GET?

Comment: No, you just need to make sure your that your object matches your JSON.